# Multi Site using Template in asp.net 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates, web

I have an ASP.Net site in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express Framework 3.5 which works absolutely fine on its own.

I'm now after the best way of using the same code base, but for multiple sites.

For example:

```
http://websiteaddress/SiteNumber1/Album.aspx or     
http://websiteaddress/SiteNumber2/Album.aspx
```

What is the best way to go about this?
Should I go about using a rewrite rule using Intelligencias Rewrite, or somehow using specific Site Masters. This question may have been answered somewhere else, but I'm not completely sure what I should be searching for?
I don't have permissions to mess with IIS or anything.

Maybe someone knows of a tutorial doing the same thing.
Hopefully I've explained this well enough, but if not, feel free to ask questions!

Thanks

Comment: Technically I would like SiteNumber1 / SiteNumber2 to be dynamic and found in my database in case that makes a difference to anybody's answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use can create the `Album.cs` file and then u can use it. Or second method is that you can create a class file and then convert it into `album.dll` then u can use it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to do it is to do a Custom Transformation using Intelligencias Rewrite tool. For example:

```
<rewrite url="^/([\w-_]+)" to="~/default.aspx?Site=${SiteNameToIdTransform($1)}" processing="stop" />
```

modified, but mainly taken from http://runtingsproper.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/advanced-url-rewriting-for-rest-of-us.html